# Why JQuery click() method is not working?

Tags: jquery

Im tried to hide HTML elements(a h1 tag) using JQuery. Its working when call my function through a onClck() event. but Its not working when I tried to hide h1 element using JQuery click() methode. Im realy confuced.

### here is my working sample code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
function hideMe(){
    $("#h1").hide("slow");
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1 onClick="hideMe()" id="h1">Hello World</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

### here is my not working sample code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#h1").click(function(){
    $("#h1").hide("slow");
})
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1 id="h1">Hello World</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

### Download my code samples

http://dzine.us/download/jquery_confuced.zip

Please help me to understad why above code is not working. Thankyou.

Comment: you need a `$(document).ready()` handler - should be described in any introductory lesson on jQuery

Comment: FWIW, this question must have been asked _hundreds_ of times here, albeit every time it'll have a different subject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589187/jquery-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that your [DOM is fully loaded](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) before adding event listeners, do this with `$(document).ready()`. Or for short:

```
$(function(){
    $("#h1").click(function(){
        $(this).hide("slow");
    })
})
```

And FYI, since the click function is called by `#h1`, you can use `$(this)` instead of recreating a jQuery collection using a selector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your binding inside the `DOMReady` function, otherwise your elements do not exist when the script is evaluated.

Update as follows:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#h1").click(function(){
        $("#h1").hide("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be within the `$(document).ready(function() {...})` handler as you have to load the DOM first and then the jQuery code can be executed (once the DOM is loaded).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#h1").click(function(){
         $("#h1").hide("slow");
     });
});
```